# Teams is unable to communicate with Skype with error 504/1008

Tags: microsoft-teams, skype

I have 2 tenants and in one of them Teams can send/receive messages just fine, in another tenant, i can search for external contacts (Skype) but I cannot send or receive messages it always gives me this error message:

"We ran into a problem sending your message. Please share diagnostic code 504/1008 with your admin to help them troubleshoot the issue."

Troubleshoot I did:

- The configurations in Teams admin center are exactly the same in both tenants
- I cannot confirm (I´m a global reader but some settings I cannot see) but it´s possible that we have some differences in Azure, although I don´t think this impacts Teams
- Checked the logs and the only thing related i could find was this:

SfBInteropServiceGateway: Interop message: 1675175961408 failed with unknown errorcode. {"messageId":"1675175961408","Thread.Id":"19:prhjiknlw6vvfq5v35jveri5au3icj3utj3udd2ks5ejapmefvjq@sfc.unq.gbl.spaces","errorCode":"504/1008","status":"RecipientPresence: isUnifiedPresence=undefined, status=Unknown, availability=Offline","type":"unknown"}

- The options Set-CsExternalAccessPolicy -EnablePublicCloudAccess and Set-CsTenantFederationConfiguration-AllowPublicUsers are also exactly the same in both tenants
- search on the web didn´t do much

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!